# Unable to Enter Username and Password on way2automation.com

Tags: java, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting Following error message while trying to enter username and password in way2automation registration page:

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
>   **org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible**

Following is my code:

```
public void SignIn() {
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Signin")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"load_form\"]/fieldset[6]/input")).sendKeys("ankit_21");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"load_form\"]/fieldset[7]/input")).sendKeys("automation");

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also tried search the element by

```
findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("automation");
```

Didn’t Work as well.

Please Help

Comment: You need to switch to the new window.

Comment: Please paste the html portion of your code here

Answer (score 0):

To enter **`username`** and **`password`** in way2automation `registration page` you can use the following code block :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='user_email']")).sendKeys("ankit_21");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='user_password']")).sendKeys("automation");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to the popup window first, do the actions there, and then switch back to the main window when you need to work on it again.

```
String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle(); //main window
    WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(By.className("btn-primary"));
    loginButton.click();

    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); //gets all the windows (this code assumes there are only two in total
    for (String windowHandle : handles) {
        if (!windowHandle.equals(parentWindow)) {
            driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle); //switches to the popup window
        }
    }

    WebElement usernameField = driver.findElement(By.id("user_email"));
    usernameField.click();
    usernameField.sendKeys("ankit_21");
    WebElement passwordField = driver.findElement(By.id("user_password"));
    passwordField.click();
    passwordField.sendKeys("automation");

    driver.close(); //close child window
    driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow); //control the parent window
```